# Custom layout in Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, layout, aggregate, kibana

I have some particular data. I would like to create a report with a few columns. 
Something like this:

---

### | *MethodName | <0.1s | 0.1-0.2s | 0.2-0.3s | > 0.3s* |

### | read    | 20 | 30 | 3 | 1 |

...

For instance, the number *20* means that using method **read** *20* files have finished before *2* seconds passed etc.

So far, I was able to do this: 
[image: myLayout]

As you see I got 4 tables, each of them with **MethodName** column but I want only one **MethodName** column because I have to export this to pdf format and put this on vertical pages.

**Edit:**

I've created something like this (using dates instead of methods but the main idea is the same):
[image: NewLayout]
But still... This is not what I wanted. Though, this time, I have to only change milisecElapsedRange column into four columns (each of them with separate range).

Comment: Anybody? Maybe some hints?